# Is Professor X dead or alive

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, x-men-the-last-stand

In *X-Men: The Last Stand* Professor X dies, so how is he alive in *X-Men: Days of Future Past*? That makes no sense if he dies before they reach that future.

Comment: Duplicate of [What happened to Charles Xavier after X-Men 3?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19698/what-happened-to-charles-xavier-after-x-men-3) and also of [this](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/31579/professor-xavier-still-alive).