# Scott Summers's status in X-Men: The Last Stand?

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-the-last-stand

In the movie X-Men: The Last Stand the resurrected Jean Grey comes back as the Phoenix and kills both Scott Summers and Xavier becoming being killed herself by the Wolverine.

I've seen many examples of Xavier living in the future war with the Sentinels in both the movies, comic books and other alternative time lines of the X-Men. In the Last Stand movie Scott Summers's death isn't actually shown on screen, and none of the characters actually say that he's dead.

Is there anything in the comics or cut scenes for the movie that would clarify that he's really dead, and doesn't come back like Xavier does?

Comment: @BlueMoon93 I think that was a typo, I believe they mean scott summer being dead

Comment: Scott Summers ran off on his own to grieve over Jean and she killed him for it. So there wasn't anyone else around to know he was dead. As far as they are probably concerned, Scott is still AWOL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's pretty definite that Jean killed Scott. She never comes right out and says it, since her Dark Phoenix persona remains dominant for most of the movie, but there are several lines of dialogue that make it clear that's what happened.

Jean almost admits what she did in the exchange with Logan, when she returns to the X Mansion. Dark Phoenix Jean starts to come on to him very strongly, but when he backs off, she seems to "regain her senses", followed by this dialogue:

> LOGAN: Where's Scott? Jean?
>
> JEAN: Where am I?
>
> LOGAN: You're in the mansion. You need to tell me what happened to Scott. Jean, tell me what happened to him.
>
> JEAN: Oh, God.
>
> LOGAN: Look at me. Stay with me. Talk to me. Look at me. Look at me.
>
> JEAN: No...  (starts to weep) Kill me.
>
> LOGAN: What?
>
> JEAN: Kill me before I kill someone else.

Right after this, Jean seems to return to her Dark Phoenix state and leaves. Xavier then finds Logan and, who says:

> ORORO: What happened?
>
> CHARLES: What have you done?
>
> LOGAN: I think she killed Scott.

Later, when Xavier tracks Jean down at the house, and tries to convince her to get help controlling her power, one of the things he says is:

> CHARLES: Trust me. You're a danger to everyone. But I can help you.
>
> ERIC: I think you want to give her the cure.
>
> XAVIER: Look at Scott. You killed the man you loved because you couldn't control your power.
>
> JEAN: No! Stop it!

Admittedly she's in a bad condition at this point, but she doesn't seem to be denying the act so much as trying to get Charles to stop talking about it, and stop trying to "get in her head".

---

On a closely related note, the events of this movie were essentially erased from the timeline by *X-Men: Days of Future Past*. The ending of that movie shows both Jean and Scott alive and well at the X Mansion, and apparently happily together as a couple.

Comment: `Kill me before I kill someone else` is the best answer to the question. I didn't know she said that. Can you answer if this movie differs from say "official" X-Men canon (if there is such a thing).

Comment: there's no such thing as a single "official" continuity, but I can tell you in the _comics_ continuity, Scott outlives Jean and goes on to have a relationship with Emma Frost. But Jean has a habit of coming back from the dead, so much so that it's a joke among the characters in-universe.

Answer (score 2):

My memory's a bit foggy as it's been a while since I've seen the movie, but I seem to recall in the scene where Jean Grey/Phoenix come back to the mansion that she ends up telling Wolverine that she killed him.

So yes, Scott Summers is dead as of X-Men: Last Stand

> Also, Xavier's consciousness is transferred into a comatose body, but
>  they never explain how he has his normal body back in X-Men: Days of
>  Futures Past.

Comment: He transfered his mind to his brain dead twin but how he got paralyzed again is a question. Anyway you can add post credit scene video too https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSkn3KYwmtc or can link related answer http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/19700/1190

Comment: @AnkitSharma That post-credit scene has nothing to do with this answer, though. We're not discussing Xavier here anyway.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson they mentioned Xavier, that's why what I've got is in spoiler tag cause it kinda answers but references another movie

Comment: @DForck42 Well, sure. I was just replying to his suggestion of adding that YouTube video, which might seem overkill for what is only a very tangentially related point in the answer.

Comment: oh wow, I've never seen that ending before. Thanks :)